# XML SAXParser reformat if else Java/Android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax

I have the following problem:

I am using an XML SAXParser to parse an xml file and create dynamicly classes and set their properties.

I have written code that works now to make 4 classes and set the properiets of the classes but the problem is that the code is one big conditional case (if/else if/else) and that it is very difficult to read.

I would like to parse the xml so I can create 15 different classes, so the code is getting very big.

Now the exact question is how to refactor the if/elseif/else to better readable code? I've searched around for a while now and found some methods like using a map or the command pattern but I don't understand how to use this?

This is the code I'm currently using and that is working:

```
public class XmlParserSax extends DefaultHandler {

List<Fragment> fragments = null;
String atType = null;
String typeObject;
String currentelement = null;
String atColor = null;
RouteFragment route = null;
ChapterFragment chapter = null;
FirstFragment first = null;
ExecuteFragment execute = null;
StringBuilder textBuilder;

public XmlParserSax() {
    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    try {
        /**
         * Create a new instance of the SAX parser
         **/
        SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = saxPF.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /**
         * Create the Handler to handle each of the XML tags.
         **/

        String file = "assets/test.xml";
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(file);

        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(in));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    atColor = attributes.getValue("color");
    atType = attributes.getValue("type");
    currentelement = localName;
    textBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("template")) {

        if (atType.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {

            route = new RouteFragment();
            typeObject = "route";
        } else if (atType.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {

            chapter = new ChapterFragment();
            typeObject = "chapter";
        } else if (atType.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first = new FirstFragment();
            typeObject = "first";
        } else if (atType.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute = new ExecuteFragment();
            typeObject = "execute";
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("number")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setNumberTextcolor("#" + atColor);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("maxnumber")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setMaxNumberColor("#" + atColor);
        }

    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setTitleColor("#" + atColor);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first.setTitleColor("#" + atColor);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("subtitle")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first.setSubtitleColor("#" + atColor);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute.setTextColor("#" + atColor);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    String text = textBuilder.toString();
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("template")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
            fragments.add(route); // nieuw routefragment
                                    // toevoegen aan de lijst

        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            fragments.add(chapter); // nieuw chapterfragment
                                    // toevoegen aan de lijst

        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            fragments.add(first);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            fragments.add(execute);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
            // route.setOmschrijving(text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute.setText(text);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("background")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("route")) {
            // route.setKleur("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute.setBackgroundColor("#" + text);

        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("number")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setNumber(text);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("maxnumber")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setMaxNumber(text);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("chapter")) {
            chapter.setTitle(text);
        } else if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first.setTitle(text);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("subtitle")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("first")) {
            first.setSubtitle(text);
        }
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("square")) {
        if (typeObject.equalsIgnoreCase("execute")) {
            execute.setBorderColor("#" + text);

        }
    }
}

public List<Fragment> getList() {
    return fragments;

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    textBuilder.append(ch, start, length);

}
```

}

Comment: i had answered something similar some time back, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417363/parsing-an-xml-file-in-android/13417932#13417932

Comment: @Atrix1987 I don't see why your version is less code? U still use a lot of if else?

Comment: there is another way of doing it, using start element and end element listeners, i'll post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way of doing this; using startElementListener and EndTextElementListeners

First define your root element:

```
    RootElement root = new RootElement("root");
```

Define your child elements

```
    Element nodeA = root.getChild("nodeA");
    Element nodeB = root.getChild("nodeB");
    Element nodeC = root.getChild("nodeC");
```

Now set the listeners

```
    root.setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {
            public void start(Attributes attributes) {
                foundElement = true;// tells you that you are parsing the intended xml
            }
        });

    nodeA.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
            public void end(String body) {
                //populate your pojo
            }
        });
```

This way you can do away with all those if-else statements and booleans, but you have to live with the N number of listeners.

Comment: hmm, I will take that into account, now I'm trying to work with enums and the code looks a bit more readable :)